# Layered Structure of Computer Networking

Tags: networking, architecture

Imagine a protocol stack, wherein there is no transport layer. How would that affect the design of: 
• The Network Layer? 
• The Link Layer? 
• The Application Layer?

Now, imagine a protocol stack with only two layers: The Application Layer & The Everythingelse Layer.

• What would the consequences be of such a networking architecture?
• What would advantages (if any) be?
• What would disadvantages (if any) be?

Comment: More layers  mean more independent modules. If you have to just upgrade "everything else" layer, you have to scratch your head. you might have to read some Tcp/ip stack tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layered architecture approach of TCP/IP protocol stack is for Distribution of work at respective layers. If you have fewer layers, you will also have to modify other adjacent layers so that the task performed by absent layers are performed by someone else.

Making a two layer only system would need a very complex layer (in your case "Everything Else" layer). which is not practical.